# Convert currency in SQL

Tags: mysql

How can I convert the inconsistent value column (containing both number and text) into a number?
like this `4.5M => 4500000`, `7M => 7000000`

I tried to convert, but it doesn't give me the expected answer. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can `CAST` the column into decimal then multiply the number by 1000 if `K`, 1000000 if `M`, and so on :

```
SELECT *, CAST(col AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * IF(col LIKE '%K', 1000, 1000000) as number
FROM mytable
WHERE col LIKE '%[KM]'
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, logical operators evaluate to 1 (for TRUE) and 0 (for FALSE), we can use this as the following:

```
SELECT CAST(text_num AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * (text_num like '%M') * 1000000 +
       CAST(text_num AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * (text_num NOT like '%M') AS num
FROM tbl_name
```

If you have units other than `M`, you can expand the query as the following:

```
SELECT CAST(text_num AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * (text_num like '%K') * 1000 + 
       CAST(text_num AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * (text_num like '%M') * 1000000 +
       CAST(text_num AS DECIMAL(10,2)) * (text_num NOT like '%K' AND text_num NOT like '%M') AS num
FROM tbl_name
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9vN-uUqd)

Comment: Warning: `'!' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use NOT instead`   (see: [The !, operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#:~:text=1%2B1.-,The%20!%2C%20operator,-is%20a%20nonstandard))

Comment: Yea, and I rarely use it, thanks for this note :)